# VS 2022 develoment - ASP.NET Core - Define Environment in csproj configuration rather than launchSettings

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, configuration

I my current project i would like to be able to change my DOTNET environment via the condifuration dropdow selection rather than with launchsettings.

I understand that i can define this property into launchSettings.json with some profile :

```
"Dotnet - Development Local (Http)": {
  "commandName": "Project",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "launchUrl": "swagger",
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
  },
  "dotnetRunMessages": true,
  "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5041"
},
```

But for some reasons i'm trying to keep this config tied to solution configuration. So 'im trying to do something like this (in csproj) :

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='MyConfiguration|AnyCPU'">
    <EnvironmentName>MyWantedEnv</EnvironmentName>
</PropertyGroup>
```

But after a lot of tries changing some writing or trying other keywords i'm still not able to define this environment with **this** file.

Is someone have any ideas about this concerns ?
Is it possible to define this in csproj or must i specify the environnement only in launchsettings ?

Thanks you all.

Comment: you can set this in program.cs: Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT", "Development");

Comment: Sorry for the delay. In fact what i wanted to do was to bind solution config and ASP.net core environment. It was just for a test and it's certainly a bad idea. I finally succed into getting assembly config value and set environment variable with the line of code you provided.